# Which statistical test to use to check if the variance is due to a particular factor?

Tags: statistical-significance, percentage

I have 2 observations for 9 departments within an organization - one observation corresponds to the fraction of women among all employees in the department and other observation corresponds to fraction of white women among all employees in that department. The question I am trying to address is, whether white women % in each department is in line with total women % for each department or not? Which statistical test should I use for this kind of analysis? Whether the distribution across the departments is in line with the overall representation of women in each department?

Comment: Do you have access to each numerator and denominator?

Comment: Hi @rolando2 , yes I have the actual numbers as well if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @rolando2: looking forward to your support

Comment: The way you've proposed -- "women" and "white women" -- it would be difficult to obtain "clean" and interpretable results.  One variable is inseparable from the other.  I would instead assess the association of the two variables race and gender, as by a chi-squared test of independence.